# Local barrier implies barrier?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

there. This is part of the textbook of Gibarg's PDE:
[image]

My question is that how to verify the part in red?

**How to know $\overline w$ is continous in $\overline \Omega$?**

Thanks so much! Your help will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since $m=\inf_{N-B}w\gt 0$, on $\partial B$, $m\le w$, and so $\overline{w}|_{\partial B}=m$, as $w$ is superharmonic it is continuous. The $\inf$ of two continous functions is continuous, thus $\overline{w}$ is continuous.